# Query with Indexes slower than without Indexes

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, innodb, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and my storage engine is InnoDB.

I have a table with 1 million rows containing with the columns:

- ID (primary key)
- FirstName
- LastName
- foreign_key_id (foreign key, NOT NULL)
- foreign_key_id2 (another foreign key, default NULL)

The rows are seperated under:

- 25% with **foreign_key_id** value 1 and **foreign_key_id2** NULL
- 25% with **foreign_key_id** value 1 and **foreign_key_id2** NOT NULL
- 25% with **foreign_key_id** value 2 and **foreign_key_id2** NULL
- 25% with **foreign_key_id** value 2 and **foreign_key_id2** NOT NULL

With the following indexes:

- index **foreign_key_idx** on **foreign_key_id**
- index **foreign_key_2_idx** on and **foreign_key_id2**
- composite index **foreign_key_comp_idx** on **(foreign_key_idx, foreign_key_2_idx)**

**I perform the following queries:**

> Query 1 - without indexes:

```
SELECT *
FROM table tbl
IGNORE INDEX(foreign_key_idx, foreign_key_2_idx, foreign_key_comp_idx)
WHERE tbl.foreign_key_id = 1 AND tbl.foreign_key_id2 IS NOT NULL
```

> Query 2 - with indexes (no composite index):

```
SELECT *
FROM table tbl
IGNORE INDEX(foreign_key_comp_idx)
WHERE tbl.foreign_key_id = 1 AND tbl.foreign_key_id2 IS NOT NULL
```

> Query 3 - with composite index (no other indexes):

```
SELECT *
FROM table tbl
IGNORE INDEX(foreign_key_idx, foreign_key_2_idx)
WHERE tbl.foreign_key_id = 1 AND tbl.foreign_key_id2 IS NOT NULL
```

**The results:**

> Query 1 (no indexes) performs a **full table scan** and uses **1 million records** with a
>   total duration of **0.37 seconds.**
>
> Query 2 (indexes, no composite index) performs a **non-unique key lookup** on **foreign_key_idx index** and
>   uses 500K records with a total duration of **0.6 seconds**.
>
> Query 3 (composite index only) performs an **index range scan** on **composite index** and uses 480K
>   records with a total duration of **0.13 seconds**.

What I really don't understand is: why is **query 2** (with indexes) always performing slower than **query 1** (without indexes)? I'm really really stuck and need some help...

I've tested the queries above with different amount of rows, like 1k, 10k, 20k, 50k, 100k, 200k, 250k, 500k, 1M etc, always with the same ratio (25%), and the results where the same (query 2 always performing slow)

Thank you in advance, really appreciate any kind of input!

**Edit (2 May 2016)**

**SHOW CREATE TABLE COMMAND:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `FirstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `LastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `foreign_key_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `foreign_key_id2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
   KEY `foreign_key_idx` (`foreign_key_id`),
   KEY `foreign_key_2_idx` (`foreign_key_id2`),
   KEY `foreign_key_comp_idx ` (`foreign_key_id`,`foreign_key_id2`),

   CONSTRAINT `foreign_key_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign_key_id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `foreign_key_2_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign_key_id2`) REFERENCES `table3` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1515998 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**EXPLAIN PLANS:**
[image]

Not sure if important, but table2 has 20 records and table3 also 1 million.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before I dig into this.  Also provide the `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ` output for each.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you. Added the CREATE TABLE and EXPLAINS!

Answer (score 3):

`FOREIGN KEY` is a red herring; the indexes (KEYs) are relevant.

An index is stored in a BTree.  BTrees are efficient for looking up a single item and for scanning a range of item with the same or sequential values.  This is what your test cases are doing.

But, once an item is found in the index, the query needs to reach into the 'data' because you asked for other columns `*` (in `SELECT *`).  This means reaching over into the data BTree, which is ordered according to the `PRIMARY KEY`.

This back-and-forth between the index and the data is somewhat costly.  In general, if more than 20% of the rows are needed, it is more efficient to simply scan the table (a "table scan"), ignoring the index.  (Caveat:  the "20%" depends on the phase of the moon; it might be 10%, or 30% or something else.)

*Usually* the optimizer will correctly pick between using the index (when a small percentage is needed) and doing a table scan.  So, *usually* you should not worry.

Another issue...  A common problem is running timings is 'caching' which makes the same query take less time the second time you run it.  Or makes other queries run faster (because it cached what they need).  This adds confusion.

Sometimes it is worth running `ANALYZE TABLE tbl;` to recompute the "statistics" used in making the decision to do a table scan or use the index.  But I would not put too much faith in the being the standard 'fix'; it can also make things worse.  (`ANALYZE` does some 'random' probes to guestimate the stats.)

Only one time in a thousand have I seen a query that really needs `FORCE INDEX` or one of the similar hints.  So, I advise against that.

What are you going to do with 250K or 500K rows in the client?  That will choke most clients.  And it does not sound like something you do frequently?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I know beforehand that indexing this table/columns will have a negative impact?

Comment: Usually adding an index should *never* have a negative impact on reading queries. The DBMS should *always* find the optimal execution plan and hence use the index only when the execution plan is *better* then the access without the index. But it seems the optimizer can make mistakes, so if a query gets way too slow because of such a mistake, you can help it by applying `IGNORE INDEX`. (Usually the optimizer gets better and better, so when updating your DBMS to a new version you can often get rid of such workarounds.)

Answer (score 2):

The thing that surprises me is that query 3 is faster than query 1 :-)

You want 25% of the table's records. So simply reading the table sequentially should be the fastest approach. (At least this is what I would do, and what most DBMS do in that situation.)

Using the composite index is okay, because it suffices to know which records to select. But to go through a tree only to end up with 25% of all records which must be accessed one by one, seems like a big task. As mentioned, it is surprising that this runs faster then the full table scan for you. Maybe the physical records happen to be about as ordered as needed, so you don't have to go from one section to the other and back and forth, which is what usually happens when coming from an index. (Explanation: Let's say you find a matching record reference in the index for table section A on the disk, the next match happens to be in sector B, the third in sector A again, ... this can take long. If you are lucky however, you find all records in one sector first then in the other. With a full table scan you read sector after sector without having to switch from one to the other and back. So the full table scan is guaranteed to be rather fast, whereas the acccess via index may be fast or slow.)

Now to query 2: The index only points to records that might match (50% of the records of the table where only half of them is a match). That means you have to go through the tree as described, only in order to still have read half of the table's records. This is just too much work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I know beforehand that indexing this table/columns will have a negative impact?

Answer (score 0):

The indices are really bad because there are only two possible values in each. So I suppose, using the index reduces the amount of rows to check not significantly enough in comparison to not using the index at all and simply check all entries.

The combined index at least divides the table in 4 parts, so only one fourth of the table must be searched, and this is sufficient to compensate asking the index first.